# Using static functions within a duplicated FreeRtos Task

Tags: c, memory, static, task, freertos

I am using FreeRtos and have a Task that I am using multiple times. I am calling static functions within the Task. During the multiple uses of this task, will the static functions be overwritten with one another's data or cause some type of issue? Eg...

```
static int addSomeNumbers(int x)
{
   int num1 = 4;
   int num2 = 83;
   int num3 = 65;
   return x+num1+num2+num3;
}

void SomeTask(void *pvParameters)
{
  int localInt = *(int *) pvParameters;
  addSomeNumbers(localInt);
  //continue
}
```

I use this Task three times

```
xTaskCreate(SomeTask, "SomeTask0", stackDepth, someNumber0, ...)
xTaskCreate(SomeTask, "SomeTask1", stackDepth, someNumber1, ...)
xTaskCreate(SomeTask, "SomeTask2", stackDepth, someNumber2, ...)
```

The problem I am running into, is that the data I see coming out of each Task is not consistent. It seems that the second Task sometimes is using the first task's data within `addSomeNumbers` and so on. Any way to prevent this?

Comment: Where does someNumberX come from? Make sure it is valid during the runtime of the associated task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is the case.

[Static functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/static-functions-in-c)
are only about the visibility scope of the function, but not about the storage class of variables used therein.

If this is your actual code (and you haven't declared `num1` etc. as **`static`** `int`, the `num`s will be re-allocated on each task stack, and shall not see "each other" (unless you managed to corrupt the kernel by some unrelated error behaviour...).

Comment: Ok thanks, I thought each Task would have its own stack including the functions. The data contamination must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not sure whether that could be the case for certain other languages, but not for C.